# What is the n-fold composition of a linear map "T", if n is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, function-and-relation-composition

I am doing an assignment on Groups of Linear Transformations. Here is a defnition with regards to n-fold compositions:

*"Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ denote the n-fold compositions of $T$ with itself as $T^{n}$. For instance, the two-fold composition, $T\circ T$ is denoted $T^{2}$. Let $T^{-n}$ denote the n-fold composition of $T^{-1}$."*

So, with the above definition in mind, $T^{1}$ is just T, but what would $T^{0}$ yeild?

Comment: Identity linear function.

Comment: @WillM. Thanks but can you explain how/why? Or is this just the way it is defined?

Comment: If $T$ were invertible and you wanted the relation $T^{p+q}=T^p \circ T^q$ to hold for all integers $p$ and $q,$ then $T^0$ has to be the identity.

Comment: @WillM. Thanks. If you write this as an answer I can accept it...

Comment: You are welcome. I am OK like this. I'm lazy to write it down, :P